# Bash 複数コマンドの結果を1行で表示したい

Tags: bash, awk

お世話になっております。

```
uname -n ; cat /proc/meminfo | head -1 | awk '{print$2}'

server1
1112233
```

という結果を得ました。

この結果を、

```
sever1 112233
```

としたいのですが、何かいい方法はないでしょうか。

Answer (score 3):

[linux - How to join multiple lines of file names into one with custom delimiter? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764051/how-to-join-multiple-lines-of-file-names-into-one-with-custom-delimiter)

```
(uname -n ; cat /proc/meminfo | head -1 | awk '{print$2}') | tr '\n' ' '
```

でどうでしょう

Comment: 上手く行きました！ありがとうございます！

Comment: リンク先の Stack Overflow のコメントにもあるとおり、末尾の `\n` もスペースに変換されてしまいます。

`uname -n | tr '\n' ' '; cat /proc/meminfo | head -1 | awk '{print$2}'`

のように、`uname` の結果だけ `tr` に渡せば余計なスペースが追加されません。

Answer (score 3):

既に解決済みですが、別回答ということで。

```
$ echo -n "$(uname -n) "; cat /proc/meminfo | awk 'NR==1{print $2}'

$ set -- $(uname -n; cat /proc/meminfo | awk 'NR==1{print $2}'); echo "$1 $2"

$ printf "%s %s\n" $(uname -n; cat /proc/meminfo | awk 'NR==1{print $2}')

$ cat /proc/meminfo | awk -v uname="$(uname -n)" 'NR==1{print uname " " $2}'
```

Comment: こちらも素晴らしいです！
ありがとうございます

Answer (score 3):

私でしたらこうやります。

```
echo $(uname -n ; cat /proc/meminfo | head -1 | awk '{print$2}')
```

Answer (score 1):

別解です。
複数の行(行数固定)を1行にまとめる場合`paste`を使います。

```
(uname -n ; cat /proc/meminfo | head -1) | paste - -
```

n行まとめたいときは`paste - -`の`-`をn個書きます。

Answer (score 1):

1. 全体を `( )` で括り
2. `xargs`

でしょうか。

```sh
$ (uname -n ; cat /proc/meminfo | head -1 | awk '{print$2}') | xargs
c809051830b8 8152984
```